# Error while creating shipment with FedEx

Tags: php, magento-1.9, fedex

I've configured FedEx in magento and when I'm going to create shipment with create shipment label it's giving error like this

> RequestedShipment shippingChargesPayment - Payor is required

**How can I fix this Issue?**

Comment: its call apis check what is the response you are getting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013657/issues-using-a-fedex-webservice-via-wsdl-soap